# WinRAR wont open manifest.mf?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, winrar

I have been searching online for a reason why, however all the sites say that WinRAR should run the program. I'm watching a youtube video about it as well and it's opening fine for them. Is it because I have the trial?

Everything has been working fine but when I click on manifest.mf I get that error saying that winrar cant open a .mf file when it should? ...

Comment: Why are you trying to open it with WinRAR? It's just a plain text file that you should be able to open with any text editor.

Answer (score 0):

To get this question removed from list of unanswered questions:

File **manifest.mf** is not a RAR archive and therefore a text editor like Windows Notepad is needed to open, view and edit this file instead of **WinRAR**.